# Drupal sub-theme causes errors and doesn't inherit parent CSS?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm creating a Drupal sub-theme for the Venture Theme. I have a new directory with foo.info, style.css a screenshot and logo.

I can select the sub-theme in the Appearance tab but then it throws many errors in the admin window and the site does not inherit any styles from the Venture theme.

This is the code in my .info file

```
name = foo
description = A sub theme of Venture.
base theme = venture theme
core = 7.x
engine = phptemplate
stylesheets[all][] = style.css

regions[sidebar_first]  = First Sidebar
regions[header]         = Header
regions[preface_first]  = Preface First
regions[preface_middle] = Preface Middle
regions[preface_last]   = Preface Last
regions[content_top]    = Content Top
regions[content]        = Content
regions[help]           = Help
regions[footer]         = Footer
regions[footer_first]   = First Bottom
regions[footer_second]  = Second Bottom
regions[footer_third]   = Third Bottom
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after a few hours of searching the internet and Drupal.org as well as trying multiple combinations I figured this out.

Seems the line **base theme = venture theme** cannot be the name of the parent theme but needs to be the name of the parent theme directory/folder. Which for me was **venture_theme**.

Once I got that working I still had a lot of display issues. It looked like all the CSS styling was missing, it wasn't inheriting from the parent theme.

I had pasted in most of the regions/features etc. from the parent theme also including the .css stylesheets

Once I deleted all the lines referencing .css files and overwrote the file as well as clearing the cache everything was back to normal.